# Node 'request' package, get string instead of object

Tags: json, node.js, npm-request

```
let url = 'https://www.example.com';
let requestData = {
    "key": {
        "keyA": "value",
    }
};
let options = {
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    json: requestData
};
request(options, function(err,httpResponse,result){});
```

How could I get the result as string instead of object?

Comment: What response do you want in the frontend?

Comment: @Kamesh, I have edited the question so that it makes better sense.